# Is it a big deal if the upper parts of papaya roots are exposed like this?

Tags: fruit-trees, soil, roots, tropical, papaya

Water washes away the soil around papaya roots, leaving their upper parts partly exposed, like this:

[image]

Close up:

[image]

The tree in the photos is the most serious example I have. Yet it seems perfectly healthy, even though the roots have been like this for months. Is it a big deal? And whether yes or no, why? In the beginning, I tried packing earth around them, but the earth was so loose that it just washed away again quickly with the water. Should I do anything, and if yes, what?